# how to change alias name of shapefile in arcgis 10.1

Tags: arcgis, shapefile

Im trying to change the alias name of a ShapeFile in ArcCatalog tree.
Im new in ArcGIS 10.1 and i Want to change alias Name of ShapeFile.

But the alias textfiled is not enabel to write any word in it ...

[image: Rightclick -> properties -> generale]

have any one any idea about it ??
how to make the alias editext as enable ???
Thank you in advance , Fadel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know, Alias Name are enabled only for Feature Classes of a Geodatabase.

Try to create a `File Geodatabase` in `ArcCatalog` and import your shapefile in it. Then, in the `Feature Class Properties` window (like `Shapefile Properties` window) you can edit alias name.